# xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" not recognized in html not working

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc

im passing an attribute to html page but it doesn't display i am using spring

this is my controller function

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public RedirectView loginCustomer(HttpServletRequest request, RedirectAttributes redir){
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    Customer customer = new Customer(username, password);
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    redirectView = CustomerService.checkCredintials(customer);
    redir.addFlashAttribute("customers",username);
    return redirectView;
}
```

and this is my customerservice

```
public static RedirectView  checkCredintials(Customer customer) {
    Optional<Customer> customerOptional = customerRepository.findCustomerByUsername(customer.getUser_name());
    Optional<Customer> customerOptional2 = customerRepository.findCustomerByPassword(customer.getPassword());
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView();
    if(customerOptional.isPresent() && customerOptional2.isPresent())
    {
        redirectView.setUrl("/userdashboard.html");
        redirectView.setContextRelative(true);
    }
    else {
        redirectView.setUrl("/login.html");
        redirectView.setContextRelative(true);
    }
    return redirectView;
}
```

and this is my html page

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
<h1 >${customers}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>CarRentalSystem</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CarRentalSystem</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

just trying to check

Comment: Stop mixing different versions of a project. You are mixing Spring Boot 2.6.2 and 2.3.3. Remove the version from the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency and remove the `thymeleaf` dependencies as those are laready included. Finally, please stop using your custom Security solution but use Spring Security (or another proven tool) to do so. The fact that you can use a password to query a user is a security breach in itself (it probably means you are storing plain text passwords).

Answer (score 1):

I found out that i was using IntelliJ community edition which not support web development i downloaded ultimate edition and everything worked

Answer (score 0):

use "https" instead of "http" in xmlns. I also got the same error and got solved through this.
It might be because of some security reason why it does not allow http links.
I am still not sure about the reason but yeah this solution worked for me so you can try too.